# Is there a way for fire an event from Silverlight when a table cell value changed in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, silverlight

I want to fire an event from my silverlight application when a defined table row or cell values changed in SQL server, is it possible? Maybe a listener can be attach? I don't know, any suggestions?

Comment: Ô_o you can continuously execute a query and look, if the value has been changed...

Comment: What is changing the cell value in SQL Server?  Some other application?

Comment: Yes, another application updating or inserting records in table.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of MS SQL you can raise a trigger when the contents of a column changes:

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2121/event-notifications-in-sql-server-for-tracking-changes/

is a reasonable explanation of the process, or it will give you phrases to google on!